# Makefile: no rule to make target

Tags: c, makefile

I'm following this guide about [makefile](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/), but I didn't understand at all the last example and I can't get my makefile work, as I obtain the error `make: ***  No rule to make target "obj/date.o", needed by "Whatsapp".  Stop.`

Here is my makefile:

```
IDIR = ../include
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I$(IDIR)

ODIR = obj
LDIR = ../lib

LIBS = -lncurses

# Keep the alphabetical order!
_DEPS = \
constants.h\
date.h\
inOut.h\
languages.h\
message.h\
mycurses.h\
mysocket.h\
text.h\
time.h\
user.h\

DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

# Keep the alphabetical order!
_OBJ = \
date.o\
inOut.o\
languages.o\
main.o\
message.o\
mycurses.o\
mysocket.o\
text.o\
time.o\
user.o\

OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

# these two lines should tell the compilator that my .o files depend by .c files, don't they?
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

Whatsapp:   $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

Obviously, all my `*.c` are in the current folder, so really I don't know what I am missing.

Just for more clarity, here is the content of the current folder:

```
urbijr@urbijr-VirtualBox:/media/sf_Whatsapp_CLIENT$ ls
constants.h  indexbook.txt  languages.c  makefile              message.h    mycurses.h  text.c  time.h
date.c       inOut.c        languages.h  message.c             message.txt  mysocket.c  text.h  user.c
date.h       inOut.h        main.c       message_for_user.txt  mycurses.c   mysocket.h  time.c  user.h
```

Comment: Are you sure that `data.c` is present and the name is exactly as I wrote?

Comment: try `make -f Makefile` and tell us the output.

Comment: I tried and it's exactly the same output

Comment: Look at what's in `$(OBJ)` and `$(_OBJ)`.

Comment: @melpomene what you mean?

Comment: Check the contents of those variables. What's unclear?

Comment: is your Makefile *exactly* how you've pasted it above? Including the lack of whitespace before each object file in _OBJ?

Comment: yes, without whitespace. Where should i add it?

Comment: As it turns out, [*Outside of recipe lines, backslash/newlines are converted into a single space character*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Splitting-Lines.html#Splitting-Lines), so the variables actually contain spaces.

Comment: no, it's fine - it just looked like it'd been pasted weirdly.

Comment: this line: `rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~`  is referencing the macro `INCDIR`, BUT that macro is never defined.

Comment: this line: `$(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)` is trying to perform the link operation.  When linking, the `-I...` operator is not used,  What should be used, inplace of the `$(CFLAGS)`  is `-L$(LDIR)`

Comment: rather than itemizing the list of object files and list of header files Suggest: `SRC := $(wildcard:*.c)`  `OBJ := $(SRC:.%.c=$(ODIR)/%.o) `   `DEPS := $(SRC:%.c= $(IDIR)/%.h)` There is also nothing to actually copy the header files to the `$(IDIR)`

Comment: this line: `$(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)` will perform the compiles with the default warnings enabled (most likely none of the warnings)  Suggest: `$(CC) -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu99 -ggdb -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)`

Comment: to be able to run the makefile with minimal fuss,  (because make will fixate on the first target listed, which is the compile recipe, strongly suggest the recipe starting with `Whatsapp` be listed before the compile recipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dependencies are not as you have specified in your `makefile`. The line below specifies that all include files should be in the directory `$(IDIR)`.

```
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))
```

This is set as `../include`, but it seems you have all the header files in the same directory. Either move them to `../include` or change `IDIR` to `.` (the current directory).

You'll also need to create the output directory (`obj`) as make won't do this automatically.

Comment: @JohnBollinger When fixing this error, the program builds fine with me (with dummy code using the same names given).

Comment: Yes. I get the same error before my change and after my change, the problem is resolved.

Comment: thanks. the problem was that as I said I didn't understand correctly all the code of the last makefile example of that guide and all I had to do was just create the directories