# error: " no rule to make target 'ilclient' . stop. " when attempting chromecast alternative project with raspbian

Tags: chromecast, openmax, orange-pi, raspbian-wheezy

Hi I am using an orange pi lite running raspbian wheezy and i am attempting to make it a chromecast alternative using this method

https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-chromecast-alternative/

I am getting stuck on step 5 where im getting this error

"  no rule to make target 'ilclient' . stop. "

I believe I need something called open max for the project to work?

I am a complete n00b and have no idea what i am doing other than copying and pasting into a terminal, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

this is a `make` related error. the build system is based on `make` and `makefiles`. in makefiles are specified TARGETS. dependend on the TARGET that is named in the makefile or appended on the make command different parts of the source code are compiled an included into the executable ( http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/ , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) search in the makefile for `ilclient` and compare this [Makefile: no rule to make target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027076/makefile-no-rule-to-make-target)

a build system can consist of multiple makefiles. in this case there is in most cases a hierarchical structure :  a top makefile calls the submakefiles...
the following file seems to be the main makefile https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/omxiv/blob/master/Makefile

check if all dependencies for TARGET ilclient are met :

```
ilclient:
    mkdir -p libs
    cp -ru /opt/vc/src/hello_pi/libs/ilclient libs
    make -C libs/ilclient
```